# Symbol not found: OpenSSL_version_num

Tags: lua, openssl, kong, luajit, lua-busted

I am trying to create a kong plugin. It works great when running as part of kong server but when I am trying to write some unit tests with [busted](http://olivinelabs.com/busted/), `resty.openssl.digest` func load fails. More specifically while loading the [version.lua](https://github.com/fffonion/lua-resty-openssl/blob/master/lib/resty/openssl/version.lua)

I am not sure what exactly I am missing. Maybe some link which is supposed to link openSSL's C functions to lua.

Here is a minimal snippet to reproduce the problem.

```
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ';/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so'

local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef[[
  // 1.0
  unsigned long SSLeay(void);
  const char *SSLeay_version(int t);
  // >= 1.1
  unsigned long OpenSSL_version_num();
  const char *OpenSSL_version(int t);
  // >= 3.0
  const char *OPENSSL_info(int t);
  // BoringSSL
  int BORINGSSL_self_test(void);
]]

local num = ffi.C.OpenSSL_version_num()
print(num)
```

Error:

```
luajit: test.lua:18: Symbol not found: OpenSSL_version_num
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function '__index'
    test.lua:18: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x55b71c78ffa4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `ffi.load` your .so library before using functions from it.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef"long SSLeay(void);"  -- I have ver 1.0
ffi.load("ssl", true)
print(ffi.C.SSLeay())  --> 268439887LL
```

**Note:**
`package.cpath` is used only for `require()`.
It does not affect FFI functions.